# spring error login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application error page which has a log form. I want user to login using this form but the system throw

> "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported"

I am able to login using my application login screen but when I try to login from the error page it not allow me, following is my form configuration:

> login and erro page form

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>
        <label>User Name</label><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''><br/>
        <label>Password</label><input type='password' name='j_password' /><br/>
        <button type="submit" style="margin-bottom:10px">Login</button><br/>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

How should I define multiple forms in spring security??

Comment: You should have `<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>` notice the `/` . It is accesible from the root of your application (hence the `/`) not from sub-directories.

Comment: @M. Deinum: you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url in the page is wrong, currently it maps to `j_spring_security_check` in the current directory, whereas `j_spring_security_check` is only available on the root of your application. So when you are chaning to your error page and try to login again the URL the POST request goes to will be something like `/YourApp/error404/j_spring_secrity_check`.

Change it to `<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>` (notice the additional `/`). This will instruct the url tag to create a URL always pointing to the root of your application.